# vue js navigate to url with question mark

Tags: vue.js

my Vue js project login template click button it redirects to like this

```
http://localhost:8080/#/login to http://localhost:8080/?#/login
```

both Url show interface.
1st Url not set the local storage variable 'token'.
2nd Url is set the local storage variable 'token'.
how to solve it?

Login.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="row col-sm-12">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email address:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" v-model="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" v-model="password">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
            </div>
            <button @click="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>


</template>

<script>
    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                email:'',
                password:''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            login(){
                var data  = {
                    email:this.email,
                    password:this.password
                }
                this.$http.post("api/auth/login",data)
                    .then(response =>  {
                        this.$auth.setToken(response.body.token)
                       // console.log(response)
                    })
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show your login template especially the login form

Comment: login.vue code added

Comment: You need to clarify your question, as I cannot get it.

Comment: What is `this.$auth`?

Comment: Vue.js prototype i am set it

Comment: http://localhost:8080/#/login click login button  
token not set its navigate to this url http://localhost:8080/?#/login  
  
http://localhost:8080/?#/login click login button
here token set

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The form is getting submitted as the button you have provided in the form has `type="submit"` which is the default behaviour of a button present inside form even if you do not add the attribute `type="button"`

So replace the type submit to button o prevent form submission like this:

```
<button @click="login" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

Comment: thanks, i debuged my applications for Hours... finaly works!

Comment: I had the same issue, without explicit `type="submit"`, because my button was in `form` tag. Setting `type="button"` solved the issue.

Comment: This answer has drawbacks, see other answers using event modifier to have a fully functional solution.

Answer (score 5):

I just faced the same issue, and the provided solution did not worked for me (Vue 2.5.17).

I had to add a [modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) to the `@click` event to prevent the default behavior:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="login">Login</button>
```

Comment: This helped me fix an unrelated issue where the page was refreshing while it shouldn't have, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the **button type** to `button`, you disable default form behaviour, like pressing enter and release submit event.
Just add a [modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) to the `@submit` or `@reset` event to prevent default behaviour:

```html
<b-form @submit.prevent="onSubmit" @reset.prevent="onReset">
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the default behaviour of submitting the form using the "Enter" key on the keyboard as well, another solution is:

- to keep the `type = 'submit'` on the button
- handle the `event` parameter on the callback and process it with `event.preventDefault();` like that:

```
login(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    var data  = {
       email:this.email,
       password:this.password
    }
    ...
}
```

`Event.preventDefault()` will prevent the default behaviour which is here to submit the form on the current url with the issue we are dealing with here.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault